# A question on diagram of groups

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence, diagram-chasing

**Question:**
Assume that the rows of the following diagram of abelian groups are exact.

[image: Diagram]

Prove or disprove the following statements:

1. If $p,q,s,t$ are zero homomorphisms, so is $r.$
2. If $p,q,s,t$ are surjective homomorphisms, so is $r.$

**My attempt:**

1. By taking the same exact sequence for both rows, namely, $0\longrightarrow Z/2Z\longrightarrow Z/4Z \longrightarrow Z/2Z \longrightarrow 0$ and $r$ to be the homomorphism that multiplies by $2,$ I was able to disprove this statement. Am I correct about this one?
2. I am stuck with this one and I don't know how to proceed. Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the whole diagram supposed to be *commutative*?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Honestly I don’t know if the diagram is commutative or not. But my guess is yes.

Comment: I’m sorry. I’m new to the site. Next time I’ll keep it down to one question at a time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, take
$$\begin{array}{rcccccccl}
0&\longrightarrow &0&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{Z}&\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}&\mathbb{Z}&\longrightarrow &0\\
{\scriptstyle p}\downarrow &&\!\!\!\!\!{\scriptstyle q}\downarrow&&\!\!\!\!\!{\scriptstyle r}\downarrow&& \!\!\!\!\!{\scriptstyle s}\downarrow&&\!\!\!\!\!{\scriptstyle t}\downarrow\\
0 & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{Z} &\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{Z} & {\longrightarrow} & 0 & \longrightarrow & 0
\end{array}$$
with $p,q,s,t$ the zero maps, and $f,g,r$ all equal to the identity. The rows are exact (the maps $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms); the diagram commutes: first and last squares clearly commute; the second square commutes since $g(q(0)) = g(0) = 0 = r(0)$; the third square commutes since $s(f(a))=0$ and the image of $r(a)$ is zero. Here $p,q,s,t$ are the zero maps, but $r$ is not the zero map.

For the second one, take
$$\begin{array}{rcccccccl}
0&\longrightarrow &0&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{Z}&\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}&\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}&\longrightarrow &\mathbb{Z}\\
{\scriptstyle p}\downarrow &&\!\!\!\!\!{\scriptstyle q}\downarrow&&\!\!\!\!\!{\scriptstyle r}\downarrow&& \!\!\!\!\!{\scriptstyle s}\downarrow&&\!\!\!\!\!{\scriptstyle t}\downarrow\\
0 & \longrightarrow & 0 & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z} & \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z} & \longrightarrow & 0
\end{array}$$
where $f(a)=r(a)= (a,0)$, and $s$ and $g$ both the identity map.

All of $p$, $q$, $s$, and $t$ are surjective. The rows are exact, but $r$ is not surjective.

Cf. [the Five Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma).

(Obviously you can essentially replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with any nonzero abelian group)

Comment: Thanks so much. This was an easy-to-understand example.

Comment: I think I found a small issue in the example. Isn't f supposed to be surjective in order for the top row to be exact? I think f is not surjective. Maybe I'm wrong so could you please clarify?

Comment: @integeraddict The row is exact if at each point, the kernel of the outgoing function equals the image of the incoming function. Since the image of the incoming function is $\{0\}$, the requirement on $f$ (for exactness) is only that it be injective. I don't know where you get the idea that it needs to be surjective.

Comment: You are correct. I'm sorry about the confusion. I was thinking about short-exact sequences, which is not the case here. Could you please help me with part 1 of the question if possible? In the example I have provided, the diagram is not commutative. I also tried to prove the statement thinking that the statement might be correct, but that doesn't seem to be the case as well. If you'd like, I can post it as a separate question. Thanks so much for your time and help.

Comment: @integeraddict I have added an example for the first part.